# Python: Sharing type annotations between Protocol and TypedDict

Tags: python, typing, mypy

Take this simple example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import typing as t


class MyType:
    def __init__(self, s: str, i: int) -> None:
        self.s = s
        self.i = i


class MyProto(t.Protocol):
    s: str
    i: int


class MyDict(t.TypedDict):
    s: str
    i: int


def my_serializer(inst: MyProto) -> MyDict:
    return {"s": inst.s, "i": inst.i}


d = my_serializer(MyType("a", 1))
```

All type checks pass.

Now lets say that `MyType` is actually an ORM class with many attributes that is the source of truth for the typing of the protocol and the dict. It feels a little redundant having to maintain identical annotations in the Protocol class body, and the TypedDict class body each time an attribute is added to the class.

I'd like to know if there is a way that I can centrally define the type annotations and tell mypy that these are the type definitions for both the protocol and the dict class.

I tried this:

```py
class TypeMixin:
    s: str
    i: int


class MyProto(TypeMixin, t.Protocol):
    pass


class MyDict(TypeMixin, t.TypedDict):
    pass
```

However, mypy complains:

```
test.py:15: error: All bases of a protocol must be protocols
test.py:19: error: All bases of a new TypedDict must be TypedDict types
```

... and this one is actually a TypeError at run time.

And this:

```py
annos = {"s": "str", "i": "int"}
MyProto = type("MyProto", (t.Protocol,), {"__annotations__": annos})
MyDict = type("MyDict", (t.TypedDict,), {"__annotations__": annos})


def my_serializer(inst: MyProto) -> MyDict:
    return {"s": inst.s, "i": inst.i}
```

This runs, but mypy complains, and I assume it's all a bit too dynamic for mypy anyway:

```
test.py:12: error: Argument 2 to "type" has incompatible type "Tuple[_SpecialForm]"; expected "Tuple[type, ...]"
test.py:13: error: Argument 2 to "type" has incompatible type "Tuple[object]"; expected "Tuple[type, ...]"
test.py:16: error: Variable "topsport.events.test.MyProto" is not valid as a type
test.py:16: error: Variable "topsport.events.test.MyDict" is not valid as a type
test.py:17: error: MyProto? has no attribute "s"
test.py:17: error: MyProto? has no attribute "i"
```

Is what I'm trying to do impossible?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason why you need both a class and a TypedDict? IMO you only really need the types on the class: the deserialized dict ought to be short-lived so having it be just type `Dict[str, object]` usually is good enough. You could also use something like pydantic to simplify validation/deserialization/serialization for you. In any case, if you really do need types for both, your best bet might be to create a script that you run at build time to generate files containing your two schemas. Kind of hacky, but I don't think there's any other way of doing it.

Comment: `MyType` is something fundamental to our business and every application interacts with it in some capacity. Some apps have direct access to the database, others can only get data through an API and those often don't bother de-serializing as working with the dict representation is adequate. So I'm just hoping to have a Type definition in the tool box for every use case. Easy enough to write a unit test that compares the annotations in each to the ORM column definitions so I'll just go that route. Thanks @Michael0x2a.